# TinyMCE upgrade an modified editor to the latest version mayhem

Tags: tinymce, upgrade

It is this sad moment to a developer's life that he has to maintain and fix legacy code... In my case I have to deal with a modified (core scripts) tinyMCE 3.2.2 which I have to update to the latest version in order to play in IE9+...

So my question is if there is a way to check which files have been changed since version 3.2.2 and try to update only those cause it is an overkill to check all the code for the modifications...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear there are so many changes in so many files that most of them have changed since then and in order to work with IE9.

If possible you should never ever modify the core code. Instead use custom plugins if possible.

Comment: :( I thought so. I haven't modified the core, I've inherited this code and now I am stuck with this.

Comment: that's what i guessed. When the changes made to your 3.2.2 are minor i cwould consider using the newest tinymce version and then reimplement what has been done to 3.2.2. in own plugins.